# fade-in an incoming image, fade-out an out going image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a logo that I want to fade-in when I hover on the image, and then fade out and be replace by the original when I hover out of the image. I almost got it working but the image double fades-in with this approach and the image does not fade-out. Any changes that can be done here. Here is my html, js and css. Run live example:

```js
    $(".opening").hover(function() {
      $(".opening img").animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, "slow");
      $(".opening img").css({
        "width": 250
      });
      $(".opening img").attr("src", "http://www.letsgodigital.org/images/producten/3376/pictures/canon-eos-sample-photo.jpg");
    }, function() {
      $(".opening img").animate({
        opacity: 0
      }, "slow");
      $(".opening img").css({
        "width": 150
      });
      $(".opening img").attr("src", "http://www.cameraegg.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/canon-powershot-g3-x-sample-images-3-620x413.jpg");
      $(".opening img").animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, "slow");
    });
```

```css
.opening {
  padding: 0 4.2%;
  display: inline;
}
.opening img {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="opening">
  <img src="http://www.cameraegg.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/canon-powershot-g3-x-sample-images-3-620x413.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need JS for such simple `:hover → fade` tasks.
CSS is quite enough

```css
.opening {
  position: relative; /* add this */
  display: inline-block; /* change */
}
.opening img {
  width: 150px;
}
.opening img + img{ /* the second image */
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  transition: 0.8s; -webkit-transition: 0.8s;
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity:0;
}
.opening:hover img + img{
  visibility:visible;
  opacity:1;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="opening">
  <img src="http://www.cameraegg.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/canon-powershot-g3-x-sample-images-3-620x413.jpg" />
  <img src="http://www.letsgodigital.org/images/producten/3376/pictures/canon-eos-sample-photo.jpg" />
</div>
```

Also, if you change `src` using JS that means that your animation will always junk the first time since the image needs to be pulled from the server at the time you're trying to actually animate it.

Comment: Thanks @roko-c-buljan, this gets it done. I am now trying to make an effect that expands instead of fading but its a great start!

Comment: @CriaturaEterna in that case: Tip: expand the parent container (and set it to overflow: hidden;)

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Why not this?

```
$(".opening").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".opening img").fadeIn("slow", function () {
        $(this).css({"width":250}).attr("src","http://www.letsgodigital.org/images/producten/3376/pictures/canon-eos-sample-photo.jpg");
    });
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(".opening img").fadeOut("slow", function () {
        $(this).css({"width":150}).attr("src","http://www.cameraegg.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/canon-powershot-g3-x-sample-images-3-620x413.jpg").fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Actually this does not work because the second image fades out to invisible when mouse moves out. This is one of the reasons I haven't been able to make this work. Thank you @the-one-and-only-chemistryblob

Comment: also the fadeIn is not working is just changes the image

Comment: Edited...this may be better

Answer (score 0):

try to use stop() to stop the currently-running animation